# Can't access the Database (MAMP)

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

When I press my submit button, I get an error saying :

> ErrorTable 'form2.demo' doesn't exist

form2 is my database name which is created in phpmyadmin.

I am a new MAC user.

Below is my php code.

```
define('DB_NAME','form2');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','root');
define('DB_HOST','localhost:8888');
```

My ports are :

```
Apache  : 8888
Msql : 8889
```

Full code is as below:

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME','form2');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','root');
define('DB_HOST','localhost:8889');


$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$link){
  die('Could not connect :' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if(!$db_selected){
  die('Can\'t use' . DB_NAME . ':' . mysql_error());
}

$value = $_POST['input1'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO demo (input1) VALUES ('$value')";

if(!mysql_query($sql)){
  die('Error' . mysql_error());
 }
 mysql_close();
 ?>
```

Comment: MySql runs on 8889, but you've configured 8888: `define('DB_HOST','localhost:8888');` - change this value to `define('DB_HOST','localhost:8889');` ;)

Comment: have you checked the status of mySQL from phpmyadmin...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem have nothing to do with Mac. You have to show us more code. How the code in your form looks like? How you are sending stuff to database?

Let's assume that everything in code is set up properly. The main thing you have to check is if you actually have demo table in your database. Go to phpmyadmin and check it, if there is no table create it. You can use phpmyadmin to do that or do it via SQL query like that one

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `form2`.`demo` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

Of course code above will create table with only ID column so you have to adjust it to your needs

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply.
I tried that. After creating such table is shows the same error.

Comment: Code seems to be fine. I've checked it on my machine using $_GET instead of $_POST just because I didn't want to build form for it) and it worked. Where was the problem? In form?

Answer (score 0):

```
 DEFINE('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
 DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', '');
 DEFINE('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
 DEFINE('DB_DATABASE', 'customer');

 $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);


 if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
  die('Connect Error ('.mysqli_connect_errno().') '.mysqli_connect_error());
 }

 echo 'Connected successfully.';


 $mysqli->close();
```

**Try the msqli library instead**